# How do I repair cracks in the concrete pillars supporting my patio roof?

Tags: repair, concrete

I have two round concrete pillars that support my patio roof. I have noticed that they have cracks even though they are new. I suspect the filling of mortar and bricks inside those pillars was not good enough and now I don't know how to solve the problem. I am afraid that the roof might collapse.

Comment: Pictures, please.

Comment: A small amount of cracking as the concrete cures can be normal. Pictures are required to give a more complete answer. Also, the way you're describing it, it sounds like the column is actually made of brick and just has concrete covering it, is that right?